# How do I rewrite this conditional as one conditional instead of two nested ones?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get through a book & I'm on chapter two so I figure this part can't be that hard, but I can't figure it out.

It wants me to re-write this part as one conditional instead of two nested ones
-It also gives a hint saying that I'll have to use the AND operator-:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['gender'])) {
  $gender = $_REQUEST['gender'];

  if ($gender == 'M') {
    echo '<p><b>Good day, Sir!</b></p>';
  } elseif ($gender == 'F') {
  echo '<p><b>Good day, Madam!</b></p>';
  } else { // Unacceptable Value.
    $gender = NULL;
    echo '<p class="error">Gender should be either "M" or "F"!</p>';
  }

} else { // $_REQUEST['gender'] is not set.
  $gender = NULL;    
  echo '<p class="error">You forgot to select your gender!</p>';  
}
```

This was the solution I used:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['gender']) && $_REQUEST['gender']=='M'){
$gender = $_REQUEST['gender'];
echo '<p><b>Good day, Sir!</b></p>';
}
elseif (isset($_REQUEST['gender']) && $_REQUEST['gender']=='F'){
$gender = $_REQUEST['gender'];
echo '<p><b>Good day, Madam!</b></p>';
}
else{
$gender = NULL;
echo '<p class="error">You forgot to select your gender!</p>';  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything else?

Comment: isset($_REQUEST['gender']) && $_REQUEST['gender']==='F'

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @Bryan - I can't figure this one out. I'm just starting out so I have no idea what to try! I tried to search google to find an artice, but I couldn't find one like this...

Comment: Sidenote: Keep in mind that when eventual user input is performed, `m` does not equal `M` etc.

Comment: Your solution no longer handles the case where the user does select a gender, but it is not M or F, is this ok?

Comment: @short.fuse.5254 In order to close the question as it's done when a solution has been found, do select the best possible answer that was given which has solved and/or helped solved the issue. As it stands, it's anybody's game and will remain in the unanswered category of Stack's questions feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check your condition without nested loop. Use AND operator.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['gender']) && $_REQUEST['gender']=='M'){
    echo '<p><b>Good day, Sir!</b></p>';
}
else if (isset($_REQUEST['gender']) && $_REQUEST['gender']=='F'){
    echo '<p><b>Good day, Madam!</b></p>';
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['gender']) && ( $_REQUEST['gender']!='M'
                                        || $_REQUEST['gender']!='F')){
    echo "INVALID INPUT";
}
else{
  echo '<p class="error">You forgot to select your gender!</p>';  
}
```

Comment: @RonakPatel: You'll need another `else-if` to handle invalid input

Comment: I bet my solution is more elegant :)

Comment: @Fallen: added invalid input condition.

Comment: I used this one & added to it & got it working. This is what I came up with:if (isset($_REQUEST['gender']) && $_REQUEST['gender']=='M'){
 $gender = $_REQUEST['gender'];
    echo '<p><b>Good day, Sir!</b></p>';
}
elseif (isset($_REQUEST['gender']) && $_REQUEST['gender']=='F'){
 $gender = $_REQUEST['gender'];
    echo '<p><b>Good day, Madam!</b></p>';
}
else{
 $gender = NULL;
 echo '<p class="error">You forgot to select your gender!</p>';  
}

Comment: try the updated answer. It will also handle invalid input. And you don't need to store variable in `$gender`.

Comment: Thank you all, I posted the solution that I think is right. I put it in the post. I edited it. Please point out if I did anything wrong! I think I got it.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['gender'])) {
  echo "BAH";
} elseif (strtoupper($_REQUEST['gender']) === 'M') {
  echo "SIR";
} elseif (strtoupper($_REQUEST['gender']) === 'F') {
  echo "MADAM";
} else {
  echo "UNKNOWN";
}
```

Comment: what about didn't select a gender?

Comment: The first condition is there for.

Comment: @Bryan: check the first if statement

Comment: @Fred-ii- Nope, there was an error. Thanks for pointing me. Fixed.

Comment: You're welcome. I accidentally deleted my comment. Coffee hasn't kicked in yet ;-)

Comment: I take it you saw [`my comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958325/how-do-i-rewrite-this-conditional-as-one-conditional-instead-of-two-nested-ones#comment38791825_24958325) ;-)

Comment: Thank you all, I posted the solution that I think is right. I put it in the post. I edited it. Please point out if I did anything wrong! I think I got it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sure, but please don’t delete this one as you usually do with your “already-used” comments :)

Comment: I won't, it'll be there for "safe keeping" ;-) you could also use my comment's text to add an explanation why. You're welcome to use it and/or quote me.

Comment: Plus, Thomas Andrews also made [`another good point.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958325/how-do-i-rewrite-this-conditional-as-one-conditional-instead-of-two-nested-ones#comment38792439_24958325) which would be similar to what I said.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the heck of it! (As in, this will work, but is pretty cryptic :-)

```
echo (array_key_exists("gender",$_REQUEST))?
(strtoupper($_REQUEST['gender'])=="M")?"Good day, Sir!":
((strtoupper($_REQUEST['gender'])=="F")?"Good day, Madam!":
"Gender should be either 'M' or 'F'!"):"You forgot to select your gender!";
```

As a single line...

```
echo (array_key_exists("gender",$_REQUEST))?(strtoupper($_REQUEST['gender'])=="M")?"Good day, Sir!":((strtoupper($_REQUEST['gender'])=="F")?"Good day, Madam!":"Gender should be either 'M' or 'F'!"):"You forgot to select your gender!";
```

Look Ma, no ifs! ;-)

Comment: Why keep 4 lines while it could be the nice oneliner?

Comment: just so that it creates a long scroller :-) but let me update that version too

Comment: *"As a single line..."* - ... using a ternary operator. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just posted to see how the inline if can accommodate the OPs requirement :)

Comment: It’s so lame to introduce a var simply to echo it and forget :)

Comment: It was a suggestive comment to be added in your answer ;-) I love ternaries; very powerful stuff.

Comment: @mudasobwa: *sigh*...some people just cant be satisfied! :( but updated now, lol...

Comment: @raidenace Satisfied. Now it’s a true oneliner. Thx!

Comment: +1 for use of the ternary operator.  I started to do that but figured I wouldn't torture the OP

Answer (score 0):

Using a switch statement, you only need one `if`

```
if (!isset($gender))
  echo "no gender specified";
else
  switch($gender) {
    case "M":
    case "m":
      echo "Good day, Sir"; break;
    case "F":
    case "f":
      echo "Good day, Madam"; break;
    default:
      echo "What gender are you?";
  }
```

Comment: Although a good answer/option, OP's issue is based on the book is reading - *"It wants me to re-write this part as one conditional instead of two nested ones -It also gives a hint saying that I'll have to use the `AND` operator"*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Correct, but technically the ternary option ignores that stipulation as well (meaning the `AND` hint).

Comment: *Hm...* you could very well be right. Yet, I don't have a copy of the OP's book in my hand neither, so I guess I'll have to get me a copy ;-) cheers